# Determining the modulus of a complex number from equation

Tags: complex-numbers

$|2z+3|=|z+6|$ where $z$ is a complex number represents a circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius $3$. It is fairly easy to prove it by letting $z=x+iy$ and we get the standard equation of circle in cartesian form. But is there any way we can deduce $|z|=3$ without exploiting $z=x+iy$ e.g in cartesian form? The reason being the cartesian calculation is a tad bit tedious. So it will be helpful if someone suggests a clever way of manipulating this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working with the modulus directly, you can start with the two expressions $2z+3$ and $z+6$ and multiply each by their complex conjugate. Then you get:

$$4|z^2|  + 12|z| +9 = |z^2| +12 |z| + 36$$

Simplifying leads to: $$|z^2| = 9$$

Answer (score 0):

$$|2z+3|=|z+6| \implies |2z+3|^2=|z+6|^2$$
$$ \implies (2z+3)(2z+3)^*=(z+6)(z+6)^* \implies (2z+3)(2z^*+3)=(z+6)(z^*+6)$$
$$\implies 4zz^*+6(z+z^*)+9 = zz^* + 6(z+z^*) + 36$$
$$\implies 3zz^* = 27 \implies 3|z|^2 = 27\implies |z|=3$$